# Trying to update a JSON file in react native

Tags: json, react-native

I am trying to update the status of a boolean in a JSON file using react native. I'm trying to do it through the clicking of a check box, but am starting to lose faith!

I also imported the JSON File:

```
import quotes from './quotes.json';


_toggleCheck() {
        var checked = !this.state.checked;
        this.setState({ checked: checked });
        var j = JSON.parse(quotes);
        j.quotesArray.checked = checked;
          console.log('isBoxChecked' + checked); //
        this.props.onChange && this.props.onChange(this.props.name, checked);
    }
```

I'm getting this error, not sure why.

[image]

Comment: It happens because `quotes` is not a string, but an object, therefore `JSON.parse` is throwing this error. Try to console log `quotes` and you will see what structure it has, then you can work with it.

Comment: @drys is it possible to parse just one part of the JSON file? For example, the boolean I wish to update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution I craved for so long eventually fell out

```
_toggleCheck() {
                var checked = !this.state.checked;
                this.setState({ checked: checked });
                quotes.quotesArray[0].isChecked = checked;
                console.log(quotes)
                this.props.onChange && this.props.onChange(this.props.name, checked);
            }
```